# PUT + DELETE Http Verbs returning 401/405 from API on shared hosting webserver

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have created an MVC Web Api for some university coursework, that works as expected on my development machine (Running VS11).

However when I deploy the application to the webserver on [123reg](http://www.123-reg.co.uk/) HttpVerbs other than GET and POST appear to not reach my application at all, initially a 401 Not Authorised response was returned; however after turning off the "WebDAV" module as suggested [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/roadan/archive/2012/02/21/asp-net-web-api-fun-with-verbs.aspx) these 401s became 405 Method not allowed. In this case I only disabled the handlers as disabling both the handlers and the module meant that my application did not start at all (Error 500 without a stacktrace [custom errors are off]).

I am planning to utilise the forms membership provider to add authentication capabilities to my API, however I removed any `[Authorise]` attributes from my code when 401s began appearing.

Applications on 123Reg's shared hosting are run under Medium trust.

I have been in contact with 123Reg support, and they have been semi helpful, but have since decided that they cannot help me further (They suggested adding HttpHandlers as detailed below) (Apparently, I should consult a web designer...)

#### Things I have tried:

I have added `[AllowAnonymous]` Attributes to my controllers and/or actions with no effect.

I have added the `authorization` web.config attribute allowing all verbs and paths to all users both authenticated and not:

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
  <allow users="?" />
  <allow verbs="*" users="*" />
  <allow verbs="*" users="?" />
</authorization>
```

I have added (As suggested by 123Reg):

```
 <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <add name="PUTVerbHandler" path="*" verb="PUT" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      <add name="DELETEVerbHandler" path="*" verb="DELETE" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

This appeared to be a step forward, as we now receive 405 responses rather then 401 respones, however I am now unable to make any further progress. Additionally I have also added:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

This also made no difference.

Any help you can give would be much appreciated (I dont really want to have to move host for this application!)

Comment: I am not sure, the support site does not specify the IIS version, and they did not provide an answer when I asked in one of my tickets. They do have some support articles relating to IIS 7 but I cannot be sure.

Comment: I can confirm it is indeed IIS 7

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://forums.iis.net/post/1948512.aspx) solved my problem. I did all the regular things: added all the necessary `<handlers>` entries, disabled WebDAV, but I still had 401.3 Unauthorized.

Enabling forms authentication solved the problem:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thank you so-much! Hours of searching...tnx for sharing. This resolved the 401 Unauthorized message. (the 405 error can be resolved with the remove the webdav and add the verbs)

Answer (score 1):

I found this: http://forums.iis.net/t/1163441.aspx

From the looks of that forum post, you need to completely uninstall WebDAV for the PUT and DELETE Verbs to work. This is not going to help on a shared webhosting scenario unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, as you say, I cant do that in my situation :( - I moved the application over to https://appharbor.com/ and it worked first time.

Comment: Hi Spike! I'm having the same problem in appharbor... did you keep some of the configurations above in appharbor web.config?

Comment: @GRGodoi - Sorry it has been ages since I looked at this project. It would seem that I removed everything related to webdav (`system.webServer` section) and the `authorization` section.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was something different.
I had to go to the site folder, open the security tab for the folder, press Edit button to change group or user names permissions, find the site from my IIS 8 sites and give it a full control permission.