# MVC 4.0 beta WebAPI, PUT and DELETE throw 401 on Staging servers

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on an app, using AJAX + MVC 4 + WebAPIs.

Everything works fine on localhost (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE), but once on UAT, PUT/DELTE throw 401, however GET/POST works fine.

The WebAPIs are all public, not [Authorise] at all. All ajax calls are origin from the site site, so got nothing to do with cross-domain issues. I don't have much clue where to look into. is it to do with IIS settings/pools on those servers?

The worst case scenario, I'll just use GET/POST for all! no biggie!

But if someone know the proper solution/reason would be much appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate from this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236477/put-delete-http-verbs-returning-401-405-from-api-on-shared-hosting-webserver

Comment: Yes have a look at the WebDav. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10101574/440502

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, by simply remove WebDAV role from the IIS 7.5! everything works as they should.

thanks for the replies guys!